# How do I make pyzmq (14.3.1) and cx_Freeze (4.3.3) work together

Tags: python, windows, cx-freeze, pyzmq

How do I make pyzmq (as of 14.3.1) and cx_Freeze (as of 4.3.3) work together? By default, cz_Freeze doesn't include all required pyzmq components, at least on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following tweaks to setup.py do the trick for me, at least on Windows (see comments):

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import zmq.libzmq

build_exe_options = {
    # zmq.backend.cython seems to be left out by default
    'packages': ['zmq.backend.cython', ],
    # libzmq.pyd is a vital dependency
    'include_files': [zmq.libzmq.__file__, ],
}

setup(
    name='myapp',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='My App',
    options={'build_exe': build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable('bin/myapp.py')],
)
```